# How to enable exec() in php?

Tags: php, exec

My exec function is not enabled, I need this function for one of my files.
I would like to enable it inside my of php code if it's possible without having to make changes inside of my php.ini file.

Thank you

Comment: What version of php are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting you need to change is [`disable_functions`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) and as per the description in the manual:

> This directive must be set in php.ini For example, you cannot set this in httpd.conf.

So unfortunately, the answer to your question is no.

With that said, there's usually a workaround so that you don't need to use exec at all. Might be worth explaining in a different question what you're trying to do and see if it's possible.