# Installing with composer via PHP without using exec()

Tags: php, composer-php, exec

I developed a function using `exec()`  but my hosting company do not allow for `exec()` functions to be run. How would I get the same result without using `exec()`?

I need something with the same approach or a library similar to composer which can allow me to install, update, and remove.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
public static function install($library = null)
{
  if (self::checkExecute() === true) { // check if exec is authorize
    if (is_null($library)) {
      $result = false;
    } else {
      $cmd = 'cd ' . self::$root . ' && composer require  ' . $library . ' 2>&1';
      exec($cmd, $output, $return); // update dependencies

      $result = $output[2];
    }

    return $result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable exec() in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58401997/how-to-enable-exec-in-php)

Comment: Grammatically clearer and clearer what the user is asking for.
Title changed to better reflect what is wanted so users see its not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

You could try to see if all shell execution functions are blocked. I would assume so but I've been in your shoes once upon a time.

```
print `composer install`;
```

Comment: let me know what provider you're using and I'll look for a hack :P assuming its free

Comment: Just a question if I do that var_dump(print `composer update` . $library); I have a return 1 . Suppose all is correct ? Could you confirme me ?

Comment: [code]var_dump(print `composer update` . $library); [code]
          exit;  - I tried on my server and I have this result : Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons in /var/www/clients/client1/web3/web/demo/includes/Sites/Admin/Composer.php on line 175
phpmailer/phpmailer int(1)

Comment: var_dump(print `composer update {$library}`); ==>better same problem

Comment: use shell commands to look around such as `print \`ls\`;`. You should know, if your getting blocked on exec, your php mailer is probably going to be blocked by port settings.

Comment: print `ls`; ==> nothing happen, no result

Comment: `print \`pwd\`;`

Comment: Error: no "print" mailcap rules found for type "inode/directory"

Comment: is this a php file you're using?

Comment: oups, I make that with the terminal, inside the php file the result : Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reason ....... int(1)